# Best practices updating a table in a multithreading environment

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, locking, mutex

I'm facing some issues updating a table which keeps track of some user balances in a multithreading environment.

I have multiples classes in a service that needs to read the current balance and add/sub some amount (also I keep the detailed track of add/sub in a ledger table).

What should be the best practice for avoiding concurrency problem (storing wrong balances, etc.)

- Should I try to keep consistency with some isolation level (delegating the responsability the db engine) ?
- Should I use some kind of public locking in order to shared it across the different classes ?
- Should I have a job for updating the balance table through the detailed table?

*Appendix*
The concurrency issue:

```
a. Thread "A" read value: 1 (time t)
b. Thread "B" read value: 1 (time t)
c. Thread "A" updates value (adding 5): 6 (time t+1)
d. Thread "B" updates value (adding 3): 4 (time t+2)
e. The final value is 4 when it should be 9
```

Comment: How about [Accounting Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accounting.pdf) (by Martin Fowler).

Comment: I'd go for a [ReaderWriterLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8) which allows multiple readers, single writer.  _(there is also a [Slim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8) version)_

Comment: It's not considered as a best practice (if you're looking for a suggestion for that) to solve data source level concurrency on the application level. Mainly because of limited scalability of such approach. So I'd recommend to use data source level facilities for that: transactions or optimistic locking.